# Add css to an ID in php

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working in wordpress, and I am having a bit of trouble. 
As you see: in the page "articles" managed with page.php, it shows the categories widget at this point (see image 1),

[image]

Then, inside the page "articles", if you click in any subpage, managed by single.php, the categories widget should appear in a different position.
(image 2 is where it should appear and image 3 where it appears). I'm using a plugin to be able to manage structures through the dashboard, so I need to do it inside a php file.

Image 2:
[image]
Image 3:
[image]

I'm trying to include:

```
  if ( is_page_template( 'single.php' ) ) {
                 echo '<style type=\"text/css\"> #sub_categories_widget-2 { margin-top: -150%; } </style>';
```

positioning it in my single.php or in my page.php but nothing seems to happen. Does anyone know what I'm doing so wrong? I make the widget appear though a plugin that creates a shortcode and I can add it in the editor.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing can be achieved with css.

If you are in a single.php file, you should probably have a single class on your body or html tag. If not check [this out](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class).

So with this class at the top, now you can target your widget by page, single, page template etc...

```
.widget {
  margin-top:0;
}

 .single .widget {
   margin-top: 300px //or whatever the height of the image;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do can be simply done by Javascript.

in jQuery use this code.

```
$('#id_name').css('property_name','property_value');
```

if you want to add class on particular element you can use .addClass method

```
$('#id_name').addClass('class_name');
```

Good Luck!